# How to define the circle that this complex equation produces on the complex plane?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I have an equation as follows:

$$\text{Imaginary}\left(\left( C_1 - \frac{C_2}{X} \right) \left(\overline{C_3 - \frac{0.75}{X}}\right)\right)=0$$

where the bar represents complex conjugation
and $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$ are constants that are complex numbers, and $X$ is the complex number I am solving for.  I have kept the constants general, but I can provide the numbers if required.

I am told that if you plot $\frac{C_2}{X}$ on the complex plane it produces a circle, but I am having trouble how to define it.

I can easily find one point on the circle by setting the left-most bracket expression to zero and solving for X.  I can find another point on the circle by setting the right-most bracket expression to zero and solving for X.  After that point, I am really stumped.  I cannot define a unique circle with two points.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've been stuck on this for weeks.

Comment: "*I have an equation*" $\;-\;$ The equation has two solutions, so it represents just two points in the complex plane, not a circle and not any kind of curve. "*I am told that if you plot $C_2/X$ on the complex plane it produces a circle*" $\;-\;$ You must have misunderstood something. It is not possible to plot a complex function on the complex plane (just as you cannot plot a real function on the real axis). Besides, this has no relation to the equation you started with.

Comment: @dxiv My apologies, I realised I bungled my original equation and forgot the Imaginary operator, which I have now added.

I believe there are an infinite number of solutions to the equation.  The expression in each nested bracket can be thought of as a vector.  A solution is achieved if they have the same angle or are 180 degrees displaced.

Sorry, pure math is obviously not my main field so I may be sometimes 'loose' in my terminology.

Answer (score 3):

(*Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment*.)

- With $z=1/X$ and after folding the constants, the equation can be written as:

$$
\begin{align}
&& \text{Im} (z-a)(\overline{z}-b)=0
\\ &\iff &(z-a)(\overline{z}-b) \in \mathbb R
\\ &\iff &(z-a)(\overline{z}-b)=\overline{(z-a)(\overline{z}-b)}
\\ &\iff &(\overline{a}-b)z-(a-\overline{b})\overline{z}+ab-\overline{a}\overline{b}=0
\end{align}
$$

- See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3188403/equation-of-a-line-on-a-complex-plane) why the latter is the equation of a line in the complex plane.
- $X = 1/z$ is a particular case of the general [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), which maps lines to (generalized) circles, see for example [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357055/intuition-why-the-function-fz-frac1z-maps-lines-to-circles),  [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212130/prove-that-the-map-fz-frac1z-sends-any-line-onto-either-a-line-or-a-cir), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460548/a-m%C3%B6bius-transformation-maps-circles-and-lines-to-circles-and-lines-what-exactl).

---

[ *EDIT* ] As suggested in a comment, putting it all together:

- The $z$ line passes through points $a, \bar b$ and is unbounded, so its image via inversion is the $X$ circle passing through $1/a, 1/\bar b$ and the origin.

Comment: [+1] I think it is important to say that it is "the" equation of the line passing through $a$ and $b$. The OP can take a look at the interesting explanations [here](https://www.landonlehman.com/post/lines-in-the-complex-plane/)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. Edited the answer to include that.